# cleaning .forever logs in nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, forever

I have a nodejs forever running  service. Its creating logs of huge size and because of this i run out of space and server stops the service by throwing error "**No space left on the device**".

Size of .forever directory is 4.6 GB. I want to clean this.

My service is currently running therefore i want this shouldn't have any impact if i clean the logs.

Please find below the attached screen shot.

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: why downvote ??? any valid reason ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forever cleanlogs`

OR

You can use something like `rm *`.

This will not delete any subdirectories or any file within them.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/740808/392023)

P.S. and don't store logs inside your volume. If you still want to. Give it more space by attaching an EBS

Comment: then where i should store logs, Any suggestions and what are best approaches. could you elaborate please?

Comment: First of all, don't store logs. You will never find time to sift through all of them. If you wish to store them. Store them in S3(Best) or Increase your storage(Attach another EBS) and run a cron job to keep transferring data and clean up your folder.

Comment: how to disable logging in forever process?

Comment: -s, --silent     Run the child script silencing stdout and stderr
`forever -s start app.js`

Comment: -s, --silent Run the child script silencing stdout and stderr forever -s start app.js , please add this also in your answer, it can really help someone :)